# Create OKTA JIRA login with ruby

Tags: ruby, jira-rest-api, okta-api

I need to authenticate to JIRA using Okta via REST, how can I do that on ruby? It is possible? I never did that before, I just only want to get an attached file from a ticket in JIRA

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that you can just send the `JSESSIONID` cookie from a logged-in user (such as yourself) to the REST API. You can get the cookie manually from the browser, or write a browser extension to get the cookie and then invoke your Ruby script with that cookie's value as a command-line argument. For Chrome, you could use Chrome Native Messaging for this.

Comment: Sending both JSESSIONID AND CF_Authorization cookies worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it by setting up an Application Link to a ruby web application with 2-way OAuth, but this is quite complicated and heavyweight.

I would like to figure out a way to do it with just basic auth and no Application Link, but I haven't figured out how to yet.