# Authenticating JIRA API with okta SSO

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, okta

Trying to authenticate with the JIRA API using Java code (integrated with Okta SSO). I tried basic authentication but had no luck. The exception is:

```
2017-01-05 14:22:15.112 ERROR 5824 --- [ent-io:thread-1]
o.a.h.n.p.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor       : http-outgoing-1 [CLOSED]
HTTP protocol exception: null

java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.ensureReadOpen(SocketChannelImpl.java:257)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:300)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.receiveEncryptedData(SSLIOSession.java:340)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:366)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:118)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.validate(BaseIOReactor.java:220)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:284)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:106)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:604)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException:null
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.ensureReadOpen(SocketChannelImpl.java:257)
```

I am trying to understand if there is any other way to authenticate the JIRA API?

Comment: A work around hack can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32320888/create-okta-jira-login-with-ruby